# Server side simple function called in Meteor methods error handling

Tags: javascript, meteor

In my meteor project, I want to use generic functions in my Meteor.methods
(Mostly because I don't want users to call this functions from the client).

I'm defining this function in another file :

```
const ldapPing = (callback) => {
  try {
    ldapAuth.client = createClient({
      url: Meteor.settings.private.LDAP.URL,
    });

    ldapAuth.client.on('error', () => {
      throw new Meteor.Error('500', 'Cant join.');
    });
    callback(null, true);
  } catch (exception) {
    callback(exception, null);
  }
};
```

And I'm calling it in my meteor methods like this :

```
  'test.ldap': function testLdap() {
    try {
      const future = new Future();
      ldapPing((error, result) => {
        console.log('ERROR : ' + error);
        console.log('RESULT : ' + result);
        if (error) {
          future.throw(error);
        } else {
          future.return(true);
        }
      });
      return future.wait();
    } catch (exception) {
      throw exception;
    }
  },
```

However, the Meteor.error is not returned to the Meteor method and is immediatly throw from the simple function ldapPing, which stops meteor with "Exited with code: 1".

Any idea why ?

(This example is made for this question, ofc in this case there is no benefits to externalize this function)